# ng add @angular/pwa - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v8

I'm trying to add PWA capabilities into the Angular 8 project (generated with `ng new`).

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project projectname
```

Got the error:

```
Installing packages for tooling via npm.

+ @angular/pwa@0.803.19
added 5 packages from 2 contributors and audited 18965 packages in 6.091s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Any thoughts guys?

(the rest of `ng` commands work just fine, I'm able to serve, build production ad so on)

Comment: Did you replace "projectname" with the actual name of your project?

Comment: @DamianC yes, exactly with the key name under `projects` of `angular.json` (the only and the same as `defaultProject`. The project name has a dash, like `brand-web` (does it matter btw?)

Answer (score 0):

Who would have thought?!

After hours of trying, it turned out that the reason is this line of code in `src/app/app.module.ts`:

```
import {environment as env} from '../environments/environment';
```

If you import `environment` without alias everything works fine. Weird...

`ng version`:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.19
Node: 10.16.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
```